# How to force stop an infinit loop Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is an code snippet

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

executor.submit(() -> {
    while (true) System.out.println("1");
});
executor.shutdown();
executor.shutdownNow();
```

Are there any ways to close the executor from outside? (suggest can`t change the task itself)
**like kill -9 in linux**

Comment: What do you mean by *from outside*?

Comment: No, without changing the task, you can't stop it.

Comment: If the thread is a loop, you can invert the control : at the end of the loop, make the  thread ask if it should proceed to the next iteration. You can do it via a variable, a file, a database etc.

Comment: All you can with the actual code is to "try" to stop the thread executing the loop. If this is the main thread, then you need to kill the application.

Comment: thks for reply :)

Comment: in linux, we can force stop a process no matter what it is. so i wonder is there mechanism in java like the kill -9 signal in linux to force stop a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the javadoc for [shutdownNow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) method. It says very clearly:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing
>   actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will
>   cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so **any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate**.

So what you need to do is to change your submitted task in your code to respond to `Thread.interrupt()` method. I.e. you need to change your line 
`while (true)`
to
`while (true && !Thread.currentTrhead().isInterrupted())`
 for more details read javadoc for [Thread class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Thread.html) in particular methods `interrupt()`, `interrupted()` and `isInterrupted()`

Answer (score 0):

Threre are some ways

1. Add additional condition to loop condition like `boolean shouldContinue` so setting this to false would exit loop at some point
2. If you can write your own features (you own the app) you can write code to list all threads and force given thread to stop using `Thread#stop` (unsafe) or `Thread#interrupt` (safer).
3. If you dont own the app - like you are running some appication - you can run it with  custom `javaagent` that will allow you to do the same thing that is in point 2.

Both 2 and 3, with prober integration with eg Sockets, can allow you to do that on already running process from outside of it eg. from CLI

Comment: Just don't forget to use the `volatile` keyword in first case.

Comment: "suggest can`t change the task itself"

Comment: @AndyTurner 3rd option then.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a ScheduledExecutorService instead of a normal ExecutorService?

You can capture the Future, that is the task that is being (or going to be) executed and cancel it "from outside" as you want.

```
public class Example {
    private ScheduledFuture mThread;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService mExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void executeForever() {
        mThread = mExecutor.schedule(() -> { while (true) System.out.println("1"); }, 0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }

    public void cancelThread() {
        mThread.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Your ScheduledFuture will also inherit all the methods from the Future interface as cancel, get, isCancelled and isDone.

More information about ScheduledFuture: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html

More information about ScheduledExecutorService: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

And in that way you don't need to change the task, just the way to execute it.

Comment: Not this concrete snippet, I've basically made a basic implementation of what the ScheduledExecutorService do, why do you say that it won't work?

Edit: I just noticed that the boolean flag for the cancel method is required to notify if it should cancel even if it's running.

Answer (score 0):

If you expose the thread the executor runs you on then you can interrupt it. For me this prints `1` only 4 times suggesting the interrupt is successful.

Remember that this relies on the fact that `Thread.sleep` and `System.out.println` are interruptible. If you do not check for `Thread.isInterrupted` (like they both do) you still may not be able to interrupt the thread.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private void test() throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicReference<Thread> thread = new AtomicReference<>();
    Future<Object> task = executor.submit(() -> {
        // Keep track of the thread.
        thread.set(Thread.currentThread());
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("1");
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Interrupted: " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // Interrupt the thread.
    thread.get().interrupt();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Press <Enter> to shutdown");
    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Press <Enter> to shutdown NOW");
    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    executor.shutdownNow();
}
```